# "do for" vs "do to"

Tags: phrase-usage

I observe that "doing something for someone" is usually used when the act done is positive. Is it also used for negative acts?

Is "doing something to someone" is used only for negative acts or for both positive and negative acts?

Comment: You can listen to someone.  & Administer first aid to someone.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily.

"do sth for sb" may mean "do something for the benefit of somebody", but also "do something on behalf of somebody", for example:

- I was too shy to speak, so he **did it for me**. (He spoke for me.)

"do sth to sb" may refer to something positive or negative:

- He **did a big favor to me** (also: He did me a big favor.). (positive)
- I'll never forget **what he did to me**. (negative)

Note: In reply to @Katy's criticism, let me clarify that "do a favor to sb" will mostly be used when the indirect object is emphasized (which could be the case here) or when it is too long to be placed between the verb and the direct object:

- Case of emphasis: He did a big favor **to me, not to you.**
- Case of long IO: He did a big favor **to a friend of mine who was in trouble**.

Comment: You can do something "AS a favor to someone" but you can't "do a favor to someone."     Here's google ngram: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=did+a+favor+for+me%2C+did+a+favor+to+me&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdid%20a%20favor%20for%20me%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Katy That's why I suggested "He did me a favor". The *to*-IO pattern perhaps works better if "favor" is modified: https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=EVsh9Wjs8iwC&pg=PA81&dq=%22did+a+big+favor+to+me%22&hl=es-419&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjokuek56TgAhUmFLkGHQg6B7UQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=%22did%20a%20big%20favor%20to%20me%22&f=false

Comment: "He did me a favor" is fine, but "he did a favor to me" is not idiomatic English. You should edit your post to reflect that.

Comment: The fact that you have it in one line of dialogue in one novel does not make it grammatically correct. Even with the adjective modifier, it is still not idiomatic English. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=did+a+big+favor+to%2C+did+a+big+favor+for&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdid%20a%20big%20favor%20for%3B%2Cc0